# Automatically fit Bokeh plot to screen?

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

Is there a simple way to automatically fit a Bokeh plot to the screen used to display your browser? Right now I'm setting the plot width and height manually.

Note: when I say fit I mean that I want the plot to fill 80% of the visible screen.

Comment: This may well be coming soon.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In more recent bokeh versions, yes you can do this (easily).

plots and layouts now have a `sizing_mode` property which by default is set to `fixed`. The other values include `scale_width`, `scale_height`, and `scale_both`.

```
import bokeh.plotting
import bokeh.layouts

fig1 = bokeh.plotting.figure()
fig1.sizing_mode = 'scale_width'

fig2 = bokeh.plotting.figure()
fig2.sizing_mode = 'scale_width'

column = bokeh.layouts.column([fig1, fig2])
column.sizing_mode = 'scale_width'
```

As in the example above, your layout will need to have its `sizing_mode` attribute set appropriately to let its children plots expand.

Using the above example your plot will expand to the size of its container. It's up to you to appropriately size the container (using CSS) to suit your needs.

Note that the width/height property of your figures/plots still matter: they determine the ratio at which the bokeh layout scales.